# PDF Merge Issues

Tags: pdf, merge

I have an application where a create two separate pdfs and then I want to merger them together.

I am currently using PDFSharp to merge these files together.  I have used this in a few other apps but I am having an issue with one in particular.

```html
private void MergeDisclosure(string pdfPath)
{            
  PdfDocument inputDocument1 = PdfReader.Open(pdfPath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
  PdfDocument inputDocument2 = PdfReader.Open(DisclosurePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
  PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

  CopyPages(inputDocument1, outputDocument);
  CopyPages(inputDocument2, outputDocument);
  outputDocument.Save(pdfPath);
}
private void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
  {
    to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
  }
}
```

For some reason the second page on the merged document is blank.  if I merge pdfPath to pdfPath then the merge works.  I get 2 pages exactly the same.
If I merge DisclosurePath to DisclosurePath I get 2 blank pages.  If I open the DisclosurePath document it is not blank, it is correct.

I am not sure why just this one document will only merge a blank page.

Comment: *if I merge pdfPath to pdfPath then the merge works. I get 2 pages exactly the same. If I merge DisclosurePath to DisclosurePath I get 2 blank pages.* - This seems to indicate that there is something special about your disclosure document. Would you share it for inspection?

Comment: The one thing I do see about the disclosure page is, it is simple text with a couple of parameters passed to the body of the report.  I am thinking maybe if I set a report dataset and then switch the parameters to fields in the dataset and see if that is the issue.